# Scikit Learn Count Vectorizer does not find all tokens

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a dataset of 129,013 files and want to encode them linewise, i.e. one line occuring is one token. I used the countVectorizer from scikit learn and went with

```
vec = CountVectorizer(input='filename', token_pattern='.+')
dtm = vec.fit_transform(all_paths) # all paths is a list with all filename paths
print(dtm.shape) # (129013 , 541107)
```

In the research paper, the dataset is referring to, the authors speak about 545,333 different tokens, i.e. my tokenizer did not catch everything. To check if my dataset is complete i ran

```
for f in *; do cat $f; done | sort | uniq | wc -l
545333
```

in a bash shell indicating that everything is there. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else encounters a similar problem, the CountVectorizer has a lowercase parameter that is True on default. Using

```
vec = CountVectorizer(input='filename', token_pattern='.+', lowercase=False)
```

solved the problem.

Comment: You should also add about the `token_pattern` you are using. Because thats also not the default of CountVectorizer.